# SwiftUI - how to cancel the default list animation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there a way to remove the default list row collapse animation
without using .animation(nill) modifier on the list itself?

as you can see in the clip below, I've implemented an animation modifier on the list, but the default list collapse animation kinda disrupts the desired animation.

https://gfycat.com/cheerywelloffalleycat

I've updated the code below so you could run it on your Xcode without any dependencies.

```
  import SwiftUI

struct CurrencyComparison: View {
    @State var mainArray = ["10", "10","10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10"]
    @State var array = ["10", "10","10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10"]
    @State var secondArray = ["20", "20","20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20"]
    @State var hide = false
    @State var direction = false
    @State var triggerAnimation: Bool


    var body: some View {
        VStack {


                List (self.mainArray, id:\.self) { item in

                    Text(item)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 80)
                        .padding(.leading, 80)
                        .isHidden(self.hide)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(item)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .padding(.trailing, 80)
                        .isHidden(self.hide)
                }
                .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.red]), startPoint: .center, endPoint: .center))
                .animation(Animation.spring().delay(triggerAnimation ? 0 : 0.4))
                .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: AnyTransition.opacity.combined(with: .move(edge: .trailing)), removal: .move(edge: .trailing)))
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .padding(.top, 30)
                .padding(.bottom, 30)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 50)

                        .onEnded { value in
                            self.hide.toggle()

                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() ) {
                                if self.mainArray == self.array {
                                    self.mainArray = self.secondArray
                                } else {
                                    self.mainArray = self.array
                                }
                            }
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                                self.hide.toggle()
                            }
                    }
                )
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height + 50, alignment: .top)
        .background(Color.gray.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill))
        .padding(.top, 120)
    }
}

struct CurrencyComparison_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var staticBool = true
    static var previews: some View {
        CurrencyComparison(triggerAnimation: true)
    }
}


extension View {
    func isHidden(_ bool: Bool) -> some View {
        modifier(HiddenModifier(isHidden: bool))
    }
}

private struct HiddenModifier: ViewModifier {

    fileprivate let isHidden: Bool

    fileprivate func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if isHidden {
                content.hidden()

            } else {
                content
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: AnyTransition.opacity.combined(with: .slide), removal: .move(edge: .trailing)))

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be much more helpful, if you paste a code, which is runnable and reproduces your problem, instead of minimum copy here, where we just can "guess" what the problem might be....

Comment: @Chris thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the code in here so you could run it without any dependencies on your Xcode

Comment: thank you! i have a look at it right now

Comment: ok, i found no solution for this...i am sorry. i just can give you an up vote for your question....

Comment: @Chris got it working it the end :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I've managed to find a solution that works. By changing the opacity of the list items when the list data source change happens.

Setting it to 0 when the undesired default animation play, and bringing it back to 1 when my the desired animations start playing.

That way I can hide the default list animation without removing my own desired animations :)

```
import SwiftUI

struct CurrencyComparison: View {
    @State var mainArray = ["10", "10","10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10"]
    @State var array = ["10", "10","10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10"]
    @State var secondArray = ["20", "20","20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20"]
    @State var toggleHide = false
    @State var direction = false
    @State var triggerAnimation: Bool


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List (self.mainArray, id:\.self) { item in

                Text(item)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 80)
                    .padding(.leading, 80)
                    .isHidden(self.toggleHide)
                    .opacity(self.toggleHide ? 0 : 1)
                Spacer()
                Text(item)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .padding(.trailing, 80)
                    .isHidden(self.toggleHide)
                    .opacity(self.toggleHide ? 0 : 1)
            }
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.red]), startPoint: .center, endPoint: .center))
            .animation(Animation.spring().delay(triggerAnimation ? 0 : 0.4))
            .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: AnyTransition.opacity.combined(with: .move(edge: .trailing)), removal: .move(edge: .trailing)))
            .cornerRadius(30)
            .padding(.top, 30)
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
            .shadow(radius: 10)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture(minimumDistance: 50)

                    .onEnded { value in
                        self.toggleHide.toggle()

                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                            if self.mainArray == self.array {
                                self.mainArray = self.secondArray
                            } else {
                                self.mainArray = self.array
                            }
                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.9) {
                            self.toggleHide.toggle()
                        }
                }
            )
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height + 50, alignment: .top)
        .background(Color.gray.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill))
        .padding(.top, 120)
    }
}

struct CurrencyComparison_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var staticBool = true
    static var previews: some View {
        CurrencyComparison(triggerAnimation: true)
    }
}


extension View {
    func isHidden(_ bool: Bool) -> some View {
        modifier(HiddenModifier(isHidden: bool))
    }
}

private struct HiddenModifier: ViewModifier {

    fileprivate let isHidden: Bool

    fileprivate func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if isHidden {
                content.hidden()

            } else {
                content
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: AnyTransition.opacity.combined(with: .slide), removal: .move(edge: .trailing)))

            }
        }
    }
}
```